# VB .NET server generating Excel file on the fly

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

I have a VB .NET web application running on a server with multiple requests and performance requirements.
I have a function that retrieves some data from a DB and has to generate an excel report to show to the system users.
I somehow did it, but my solution has not the performance I'd like it to have: basically what my code does is:

- The server accepts the request of report generating
- The server fills an excel file
- The server **saves locally** the xls file
- The server attaches the file to the html response and the user downloads it
- The server deletes the file (when? I need to handle borderline cases too)

The code snippet is like:

```
Public Sub ExportaDataTableToExcel(ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable, ByVal Page As System.Web.UI.Page, ByVal ReportName As String)
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim colIndex As Integer
        Dim rowIndex As Integer

        oExcel = New Excel.Application
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)


        'Export the Columns to excel file
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName

        Next

        oBook.SaveAs("C:\file.xls")
        oSheet = Nothing
        oBook.Close()

        Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & ReportName & ".xls")
        Page.Response.Charset = String.Empty
        Page.Response.ContentType = "vnd.application/ms-excel"


        Page.Response.TransmitFile("C:\file.xls")

        Page.Response.Flush()

        Page.Response.End()

        oExcel.Quit()
    End Sub
```

As you can see the server generates the xls file locally in C:\file.xls, then trasmittes the file in the response page.

What I'd like to do, and I really don't know if it's possible as I did not found any example on this, is generating the xls file on the fly without saving it locally (maybe returning as a Stream of bytes or something like this) and then assembling this as xls file in the response page, without saving the file locally.

I tried using both Page and System.IO.StringWriter with no luck, maybe I'm doing something wrong.
The following code acts abnormally, asking me to save modifies on the file (on the server side), and downloading an xls file that has parts of the html of the page, generating errors about missing css files and displaying part of the page. So, with this approach I'm almost at zero. Here it is the code:

```
Public Sub ExportaDataTableToExcel(ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable, ByVal Page As System.Web.UI.Page, ByVal ReportName As String)
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim colIndex As Integer
        Dim rowIndex As Integer

        oExcel = New Excel.Application
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)


        'Export the Columns to excel file
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName

        Next

        oSheet = Nothing
        oBook.Close()


        Dim stringWrite As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter
        Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.Html32TextWriter = New System.Web.UI.Html32TextWriter(stringWrite)
        Page.Response.Clear()
        Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & ReportName & ".xls")
        Page.Response.Charset = String.Empty
        Page.Response.ContentType = "vnd.application/ms-excel"




        Page.Response.WriteFile(stringWrite.ToString)
        Page.Response.Flush()

        Page.Response.End()

        oExcel.Quit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using Excel automation to do server-side reporting: it has a lot of problems and there are other alternatives available.   https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=NET+Excel+reporting

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm not lucky enough to have the privilege to install stuff on the server... I think I need to face what I have.

Answer (score 2):

I know I can help with at least one of those problems you are having, Lateralus. Ive taken a snippet from our live server here to show you.

Edit: This one transmits a CSV file and we had the problem initially with the HTML showing up in the file. We opted to not use excel in this particular instance but, the problems are likely one in the same.

I believe that you need to add an additional header to your page response in order to remove the HTML that you are getting in the file.

Here is an example. As a warning, I'm not entirely sure how secure this method is. We use this within our network so it didn't need to be as locked down.

```
Dim LiveFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" &_
"Website\CSVFile.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim fileBuffer(CInt(LiveFileStream.Length)) As Byte

LiveFileStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, CInt(LiveFileStream.Length)) 
LiveFileStream.Close()

Response.Clear()
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
'I believe if you are to add the following header
'it will fix the problem with HTML showing in document
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBuffer.Length.ToString) 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=CSVFile.csv")
Response.BinaryWrite(fileBuffer)
Response.End()
```

Comment: So, for example, setting the content-length header would send all the html stuff away you say? I can add a header of my choice?

Comment: The content-length header specifies the number of bytes of data in the body of the response. That being said, The variable "File Buffer" basically specifies the byte length of the HTML allowing you to snip it out.

Comment: That's ok, thanks. Supposing I can't save the xls on my server, I can't retrieve the FileStream from the filepath, so I can't allocate the buffer. Tomorrow I'll try adding some other header, hoping it will work at least for the html noise in the file.

Comment: Ah. That would cause a few problems. Using this method I just create a temporary file on the site then delete after transmission. But, in your case if you cant save it... well, that is another problem. Hope that the logic behind my answer is able to help in some way.

Comment: I think I can save it but I should handle the problem to be SURE the user has saved the file before deleting it. Is there something simple and clear to accomplish such a requirement?

Comment: You could probably capture the location of where the user wants to save the file using the dialogue. however, if you were to use the File.Exists() method, I'm not sure if you can check the client's computer in this manner. There may be a boolean that is returned by the client if the save is successful but I'm not sure how you would reference it off the top of my head.

Comment: I've another question. If I use to save the file locally on the server, I just need interop dll on the server or the whole excel software on it?

Comment: I would assume (Don't hold me to it) that you can include the DLL files (and other ones that they reference) within the appclient folder. I'm not sure if it would require a full install to create an xlsx file. That being said, If you are trying to open excel on the user's computer they would more than likely have to have that version or higher for it to interact correctly.